# Password validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to include validation for Password to be a minimum of 8 characters include a special character and at least one capital letter .

I have tried this script as:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.passworduser', function() {
  var txtInput = $(this).val();
  var regPass = "^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-_]).{8,}$";
  var color = "Red";
  if (txtInput.length > 7) {
    if (!txtInput.match(regPass)) {
      $('#password_strength').html("Include a special character and at least one capital letter");
      $("#password_strength").css("color", color);

    } else {
      $('#password_strength').html("");

    }
  } else {
    $('#password_strength').html("Password to be a minimum of 8 characters");
    $("#password_strength").css("color", color);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="passworduser">
<div id="password_strength"></div>
```

For some expression it is working, for some it is not.

Comment: *For some expression it is working, for some it is not.* => could you clarify ? Also, you'll be surprised of what `[*-_]` do...

Comment: @Thomas: to include underscore and minus , if user want to add this thats y i have used.

Comment: See Tushar's answer about hyphen semantic in a char class. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VX08iT/1)

Answer (score 3):

`regPass` is a **string**. It should be wrapped around backslashes to make regex or passed the string to `RegExp` constructor.

```
var regPass = /^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*\-_]).{8,}$/;
```

OR

```
var regPass = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*\\-_]).{8,}$");
```

Also, the `-`(hyphen) in character class is used to select character range. To match it literally, escape it or move it to the beginning or end of character class.

---

Here's complete code with some changes

```
// Can be moved outside
var regex = /^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*\-_]).{8,}$/;

$(document).on('keyup', '.passworduser', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var color = "Red";

    if (value.length > 7) {
        // Use RegExp.test instead of String.match
        if (regex.test(value)) {
            // Method chaining
            $('#password_strength').html("Include a special character and at least one capital letter")
                .css("color", color);
        } else {
            $('#password_strength').html("");
        }
    } else {
        $('#password_strength').html("Password to be a minimum of 8 characters")
            .css("color", color);
    }
});
```

Comment: It should be  `new RegExp("^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*\\-_]).{8,}$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointing out. I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your regex simple. It's easier to debug. Try this:

```
function testPassword(pw) {
 // for all special characters
 var reSpecial = /[#?!@$%^&*\-_\\\/]/;
 // for Capitals
 var reCap = /[A-Z]/;

 // just test both of them...
 return pw.match(reSpecial) != undefined && pw.match(reCap) != undefined;
};

console.log(testPassword("asdf"));// false
console.log(testPassword("asdf5"));//false
console.log(testPassword("asdA"));//false
console.log(testPassword("asdf%"));//false
console.log(testPassword("asdfA%"));//true


$(document).on('keyup', '.passworduser', function(){
  var color="Red";
  if(txtInput.length > 7){
    if(!testPassword(txtInput){
      $('#password_strength').html("Include a special character and at least one capital letter");
      $("#password_strength").css("color", color);  
    }else{
     $('#password_strength').html("");
    } 
  }else{
   $('#password_strength').html("Password to be a minimum of 8 characters");      
   $("#password_strength").css("color", color);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, i have updated your code, here is the code below:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.passworduser', function(){
    var txtInput = $(this).val();  
    var color="Red";
    var uppercase = /[A-Z]/ ;
    var lowercase = /[a-z]/ ;
    var number    = /[0-9]/ ;
    var special   = /[\W]{1,}/ ; 
    var pswd_length    = txtInput.length < 8;
    if(!uppercase.test(txtInput) || !lowercase.test(txtInput) || !number.test(txtInput) || !special.test(txtInput) || pswd_length) {
        $('#password_strength').html('Password must be at least 8 characters. Password must contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit.');
        $("#password_strength").css("color", color); 
        //return false;
    } 
    else {
         $('#password_strength').html("");
    }

});
```

I hope, this may be helpful to you.